# c# List of references of existing objects

Tags: c#, list

I have one list of object that extend one my "base class" and another object that extend the same "base class". the structure is that :

```
private List<Extended1> list;
private Extended2 item;
```

I would create one list where I can fetch all elements as base class.
something like that :

```
private List<ref BaseClass> items;
```

How i can do that?

**Solved**
I thought that the add method of list was by value and not by reference.
I have create a list of baseclass and added real items.

```
private List<baseClass> items;
items.add(item);
for(xxxxxx)items.add(list[i]);
```

Comment: you can use [LINQ Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Linq Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx) extensions, if add one object so use method `Add`

Comment: `private List<BaseClass> items;`

Comment: Create an interface, let both implement it, and make this list of this interface. Some kind of object pool pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick example:

```
void Main()
{           
    List<Extended1> lst = new List<Extended1>() {new Extended1(0),
                                                 new Extended1(1),
                                                 new Extended1(2),
                                                 new Extended1(3)};

    Extended2 itm = new Extended2(4);

    List<BaseCls> items = new List<BaseCls>();      
    items.AddRange(lst.Cast<BaseCls>());
    items.Add(itm);


    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ",
                          items.Select(i => i.myInt.ToString()).ToArray()));

    // prints 0, 1, 2, 3, 40
}

public class BaseCls {
    public int myInt;
    public BaseCls(int val) {
        myInt = val;
    }
}

public class Extended1:BaseCls {
    public Extended1(int val):base(val) {}
}

public class Extended2:BaseCls {
    public Extended2(int val):base(val*10) {}
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can just create a List of your base classes

```
var list = new List<BaseClass>();
list.Add(new Extended1());
list.Add(new Extended2());
```

You can add instances of derived classes to this list.

You can also retrieve instances of a certain subclass by using TypeOf extension method:

```
var extended1 = list.TypeOf<Extended1>();
```

Comment: I need to have the list in one variabile list and the second object in another variable and then have all elements references in one list.